# Is static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, infinity

The following code ([online here](https://onlinegdb.com/Skl8osMPL)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    double dinf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    float finf = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();

    printf("Double infinity = %f, float = %f\n", dinf, finf);
    printf("Negative double infinity = %f, float = %f\n", -dinf, -finf);
    printf("Double infinity as int = %d, float = %d\n", static_cast<int>(dinf), static_cast<int>(finf));
    printf("Double infinity as uint = %d, float = %d\n", static_cast<unsigned int>(dinf), static_cast<unsigned int>(finf));
    printf("Negative double infinity as int = %d, float = %d\n", static_cast<int>(-dinf), static_cast<int>(-finf));
    printf("Negative double infinity as uint = %d, float = %d\n", static_cast<unsigned int>(-dinf), static_cast<unsigned int>(-finf));
    printf("dinf == finf is %s\n", dinf == finf ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("dinf == -dinf is %s\n", dinf == -dinf ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("int(dinf) == int(-dinf) is %s\n", static_cast<int>(dinf) == static_cast<int>(-dinf) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me these results:

```
Double infinity = inf, float = inf                                                                                      
Negative double infinity = -inf, float = -inf                                                                           
Double infinity as int = -2147483648, float = -2147483648                                                               
Double infinity as uint = 0, float = 0                                                                                  
Negative double infinity as int = -2147483648, float = -2147483648                                                      
Negative double infinity as uint = 0, float = 0                                                                         
dinf == finf is TRUE                                                                                                    
dinf == -dinf is FALSE                                                                                                  
int(dinf) == int(-dinf) is TRUE
```

Looking at [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity), it tells me that `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` is `0`, so why does both `static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())` and `static_cast<int>(-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())` return `INT_MIN`? What does the standard say?

Comment: You title and code uses `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` and your text says `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()`. Which is it?

Comment: @super Oops, copy-paste error; fixed.

Comment: Is this an april fool joke by StackOverflow? Marked as duplicate of nothing

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395996/this-question-already-exists

Comment: anyway, the answer is that it's undefined behaviour if the value of the float (after rounding to integer according to rounding mode) is out of range for the type being cast to. Which is almost certainly the case with `int` and the maximum `double`